# How to 'reload' source files in GDB

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb

Is there a command in `gdb` that I can use to (re)load / "refresh" source files? (*As far as I can see, `gdb` works only with source **directories**, according to [Debugging with GDB: Source](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_8.html) - and there is no specific command to "refresh"*)

#### Background about my problem:

I use a virtual machine with a debug kernel, so I can connect to a local instance of `gdb`, and can debug kernel modules. The modules are compiled with debug info on, and this specifies folders where the source of the modules is kept ([Instruct GDB 6.5 to use source embedded in object file - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579443/instruct-gdb-6-5-to-use-source-embedded-in-object-file)). I have the source directories in the same path(s) in both VM and local machine.

The problem is this - I need to do quite a bit of steps in order to get the module to segfault - and the remote gdb to go into the stack. Then I do a backtrace, and I can see the source files referenced, i.e.

```
#0  0xc0132a13 in ?? ()
#1  0xc056e551 in ?? ()
#2  0xc056e506 in ?? ()
#3  0xd8be53f3 in mymodule_func1 (var1=0xd79f9b44, var2=0x0, var3=825269148)
    at /media/src/mymodule.h:954
#4  0xd8be53d0 in mymodule_func2 (data=3617561412)
    at /media/src/mymodule.h:936
#5  0xc014fe87 in ?? ()
#6  0xc0151478 in ?? ()
```

Then I try to do say, `list /media/src/mymodule.h:954` - and I realize that I have changed stuff on the local version of `mymodule.h` file!!

So I undo the changes - but unfortunately, GDB does not see these changes! And, of course, I don't want to restart GDB - because that means I have to restart the VM, and go through the entire procedure in order to get the kernel module to segfault again :( !!

Then I try to do something like this:

```
(gdb) show symbol-reloading
Dynamic symbol table reloading multiple times in one run is off.
(gdb) set symbol-reloading on
(gdb) add-symbol-file ~/mymodule.o 0xd8be4000
add symbol table from file "/media/src/mymodule.o" at
    .text_addr = 0xd8be4000
(y or n) y
Reading symbols from /media/src/mymodule.o...done.
```

... in hope that it will somehow "reload" the source files - but unfortunately, `list /media/src/mymodule.h:954` shows that it doesn't, nothing is changed - even though `gdb` **does** recognize that something has changed, as in `warning: Source file is more recent than executable.`... (<sup><sub>so, for the time being, I have to restart entire VM and `gdb` as well :( :(</sub></sup>  )

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Resetting the directory list using the [`directory`](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_8.html#SEC49) command appears to have the desired effect.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, @nandhp - if there is such an effect, I would have never guessed by the name of the command (or the associated documentation :) ) ... will probably have to test that soon. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

From https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/review/gdb.html:

After changing program, reload executable with file command

```
  (gdb) file gdbprog
  A program is being debugged already.  Kill it? (y or n) y

  Load new symbol table from "gdbprog"? (y or n) y
  Reading symbols from gdbprog...
  done.
  Breakpoint 1 at 0x2298: file gdbprog.cc, line 10.


  (gdb) run
  Starting program: gdbprog 

  Breakpoint 1, InitArrays (array=0x18be8)
        at gdbprog.cc:10
  10                for(i = 0;i < 10;i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning means source files from which binary was made are updated with new changes.
To remove this warning just rebuild the binary you are debugging with new and modified files.